# Como colocar apenas o nome da classe no comboBox?

Tags: c#

Ao adicionar um objeto num comboBox e verificar o mesmo, aparece o nome completo da classe segundo as convenções da Microsoft: `NomeDaEmpresa.NomeDoProjeto.ModuloDoSistema`.

Como faço para que só o nome da classe apareça?

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão é apresentado o que é retornado pelo método `ToString()` que, se não tiver sido sobrescrito, retorna o nome completo(*the qualified name*) da classe .

Sobrescreva o método `ToString()`, da classe que está a inserir no ComboBox, de forma a retornar apenas o nome dela:

```
public class Myclass
{
    .....
    .....
    public override string ToString() => GetType().Name;
}
```